# attributes of GroupBy objects in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I believe this piece of code could access **name** and **group** attributes using iterator, however, what other attributes of GroupBy objects could I access, and where could I find attributes of GroupBy objects except these two, as I haven't found them on pandas documents.

```
for name, group in GroupBy:
```

Comment: where could i find it, or just based on experience?

Comment: [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation)

Answer (score 1):

[`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) returns an [GroupBy object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), which not only is an iterable containing `key/group` tuples, but being an object, you can access its parameters as attributes.

Let's take the following dataframe as an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,2,2,3], 'b':[1,2,3,3,2,1]})
```

As mentioned, by iterating over the returned object, we get the `key/group` tuples that group the dataframe according to the `key`:

```
g = df.groupby('a')
key, group = next(iter(g))

print(key)
# 1

print(group)
   a  b
0  1  1
```

This is the what is returned by its `__iter__` dunder, `next(g.__iter__())`, which calls [`get_iterator`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/6efb0b20ae13c3daaf086631e85491b81dca171a/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py#L121):

```
def get_iterator(self, data: FrameOrSeries, axis: int = 0):
    """
    Groupby iterator
    Returns
    -------
    Generator yielding sequence of (name, subsetted object)
    for each group
    """
    splitter = self._get_splitter(data, axis=axis)
    keys = self._get_group_keys()
    for key, (i, group) in zip(keys, splitter):
        yield key, group
```

Its attributes can be accessed just as you would with any other object:

```
g.__dict__
{'_selection': None,
 'level': None,
 'as_index': True,
 'keys': 'a',
 'sort': True,
 'group_keys': True,
 'squeeze': False,
 'observed': False,
 'mutated': False,
 'obj':    a  b
 0  1  1
 1  2  2
 2  3  3
 3  2  3
 4  2  2
 5  3  1,
 'axis': 0,
 'grouper': <pandas.core.groupby.ops.BaseGrouper at 0x17399312eb0>,
 'exclusions': {'a'}}

g.sort
# True
```